# conditionally hide input in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a select input with an other option when the other option is selected the input should become visible, however I want it defaulted as hidden and it should rehide if select is changed again later. I have tried == and literal === and reversing the hide show commands with != without change

currently I have

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" border="1">Certification:</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" border="1">
        <select name="certname" id="certname">
            <option value=""> </option>
            <option value="State">State</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="othercert" name="othercert" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

and JS:

```
$("#othercert").hide();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#certname select").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() != "Other") {
            $("#othercert").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#othercert").show();
        }     
    });
});
```

I am unsure where to go from here or what is going wrong - any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: or can u hard code the css visibilitiy:hidden within the #othercert tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector thinks `select` is the child to `#certname` rather than its `id`. It should be:

`select#certname` and not `#certname select`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc97bhL7/1/)

```
$("#othercert").hide();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select#certname").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() != "Other") {
            $("#othercert").hide();
        } else {
            $("#othercert").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this worked, thanks - oddly enough my syntax worked on another page with a different id name

Answer (score 2):

Your `change` selector is wrong. The `select` isn't a child of `#certname`, therefore change to the following:

```
$("select#certname").change(function (e) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndgadeb1/

---

Also you need to put your initial hide inside the document ready function:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#othercert").hide();
```

However if you wish to hide on page load then you can just do this in CSS:

```
#othercert{
   display:none;
}
```

That way it won't *flash* on page load.

---